# Get the full browser URL in Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm looking to get the full URL of the current browser window in Apps Scripts while displaying the web app via HTMLService

1. When I try this, it doesn't work because the Apps Scripts is sandboxed and I get another server url of some sort

   ```
   window.location.href
   ```
2. When I try this, I can only fetch the hash or parameters, not the full url

   ```
   google.script.url.getLocation(function(location) {
     console.log(location.parameters);
     console.log(location.hash);
   });
   ```

   source: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/url#methods

Purpose for the above:
I want a button that people click on in the published Web App to remove the browser toolbar. However, the browser toolbar is not removable in the current browser window. So I want to fetch the Web App URL and put it in window.open() as a new window with the current web app because the browser toolbar can be remove this way. But I can't seem to get the current URL.

Any ideas how I can achieve this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I found this: ScriptApp.getService().getUrl();
However, is it possible to get this URL while in developer mode?

Comment: Can I ask you about what ``developer mode`` is?

Comment: When you're deploying the web app, you can "test" the code. That is developer mode. The dev hyperlink works indefinitely with the newest changes without having to republish. see picture: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/images/web_app_url.png

Comment: The code: `ScriptApp.getService().getUrl();` either gets the "exec" url **OR** the "dev" url depending upon which mode the project is currently being run in.  So, can you get the "dev" url?  Yes, but the code needs to be running from the "dev" url.  There is no way to get the dev URL from `ScriptApp.getService().getUrl();` if the code is running from the "exec" url.

Comment: @Alex Thank you for replying. I could understand about ``developer mode``. I noticed that several answers have already been posted. I think that they will resolve your issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know what you meant by developer mode either but I took a guess at this being the answer to the question.  If not, let me know and I'll remove it.

On the clientside you can use Javascript:

```
<script>
  function getUrl(){
    google.script.run
    .withSuccessHandler(function(url){
       document.getElementById('mydiv').innerHTML='<p>' + url + '</p>';
     })
    .getScriptUrl()
</script>
<body>
  <div id="mydiv"></div>
</body>
```

In Google Script:

```
function getScriptURL() {
  return ScriptApp.getService().getUrl();
}
```

Jan 10, 2021: Tested the above code in a window.onload and it is returning the correct url with a business account, V8 runtime and the new editor.

Comment: Hmmm... Not sure if it's me doing something wrong (since i'm new to JS and Apps Script), but I get "undefined". I wrapped the google.script.run.....getscriptUrl() inside a variable and tried to return it. no go.

Comment: I added some additional code to my answer.  Perhaps that will help you.

Comment: @alex per documentation `google.script.run` is async. Use its success and failure callbacks.

Comment: That worked. It only gives the pub URI and not the dev URI, but whatever, that will do! Thank you!

Comment: seems there is a bug now where exec url is not returned correctly,  this is not working for me right now,  works fine to get dev url https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60232532/scriptapp-getservice-geturl-points-to-dev-url-how-can-i-get-it-to-point-to

Comment: I just set it up as a new webapp and I'm getting the correct url returned `https://script.google.com/macros/s/idstring/exec` I have a business account, V8 enabled and new editor.

Comment: Cooper, does not work for me as per today. Using gmail.com account https://stackoverflow.com/q/68543983/250422

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest this code for the current script URL:

```
function getScriptURL() {
  // dev URI
  'https://script.google.com/macros/d/' + ScriptApp.getScriptId() + '/edit';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution depends on whether you decided to use templated HTML or not. If you do, you could write a small function which returns the webapp URL like this:

```
function getWebAppUrl()
{
  return ScriptApp.getService().getUrl()
}
```

Now you can easily access this function by using printing scriptlets and then use it in your frontend JavasScript, for example:

```
function reloadPage()
{
  window.open(<?= getWebAppUrl() ?>, "_top")
}
```