# ScriptApp.getService().getUrl() points to dev URL. How can I get it to point to exec production URL?

Tags: google-apps-script

ScriptApp.getService().getUrl() is generating a dev URL.    How can I make it generate the exec production URL?

Comment: is this in a web app? if it is in a web app you have to make sure you are going to it in the current web appurl and NOT the "test web app for your latest code" link

Answer (score 7):

How about this answer? Please think of this as just one of several possible answers.

#### Issue and workaround:

If you are enabling V8 runtime, in the current stage, it seems that when V8 runtime is enabled, `ScriptApp.getService().getUrl()` returns the dev URL like `https://script.google.com/macros/s/###/dev`, and when V8 runtime is disabled, it returns the exec URL like `https://script.google.com/macros/s/###/exec`. I think that this might be one of bugs for V8.

If you want to directly retrieve the exec URL with enabling V8, as the current workaround, how about retrieving it using [the method of projects.deployments.list in Apps Script API](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/reference/rest/v1/projects.deployments/list)? You can test it at "Try this API". Of course, this can be used with Google Apps Script.

#### Reference:

- [Method: projects.deployments.list](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/reference/rest/v1/projects.deployments/list)

If I misunderstood your situation and this was not the direction you want, I apologize.

Comment: Good suggestion.  In order to use that method, one of the following two scopes must be authorized:  `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.deployments` or `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.deployments.readonly`

Comment: Is there any chance you could explain how to use `project.deployment.list` with my gmail.com account? https://stackoverflow.com/q/68543983/250422

Answer (score 2):

For those poor souls that get here, an expansion on [J. G.'s comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60232532/scriptapp-getservice-geturl-points-to-dev-url-how-can-i-get-it-to-point-to#comment106543032_60232532): confirmed that the result of the `getService().getURL()` call is dependent on which URL (`/exec` or `/dev`) is accessed by the end-user.

There is also an explicit clarification on that (not sure if it was present before) in the [method documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/service), so it seems to be by-design:

> If you are running the development mode web app, this returns the development mode URL.

Note that to get the correct URL you need to use a workaround [suggested by Tanaike](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60236195/11407695). When using it, remember that it requires a [standard GCP](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/how-tos/enable) to enable the Apps Script API (technically, you can use a default one for that, but it will only work for G Suite (Google Workspace) accounts with access to `system-gsuite/apps-script/` resources).

An implementation of deployment getter would be:

```js
const getDeployments = (options = {}) => {
  const {
    version = 1,
    id = ScriptApp.getScriptId(),
    token = ScriptApp.getOAuthToken(),
    page = "",
    size = 50,
    type = "WEB_APP",
  } = options;

  const uri = `https://script.googleapis.com/v${version}/projects/${id}/deployments`;

  const fullURI = `${uri}?pageSize=${size}${page ? `&pageToken=${page}` : ""}`;

  const params = {
    contentType: "application/json",
    headers: {
      Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
    },
    muteHttpExceptions: true,
    method: "get",
  };

  const deps = [];

  const response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(fullURI, params);

  if (response.getResponseCode() !== 200) {
    console.log(response.getContentText());
    return deps;
  }

  const { deployments, nextPageToken } = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());

  const requested = deployments.filter(({ entryPoints }) =>
    entryPoints.some(({ entryPointType }) => entryPointType === type)
  );

  deps.push(...requested);

  if (nextPageToken) {
    deps.push(...getDeployments(options));
  }

  return deps;
};
```

After a successful response, check the [`entryPoints`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/reference/rest/v1/projects.deployments#EntryPoint) collection to get the deployment you need. Each entry point will have a `webApp` nested object - you are interested in the `url` property of it.