# StateToken / POST Request to Apps Script Function

Tags: google-apps-script, oauth, woocommerce-rest-api

I am building a Woocommerce API integration and am working on the authentication functionality. The authorization endpoint requires a `return_url` and a `callback_url`.

I am under the impression that I can use the `StateTokenBuilder`, similar to how the OAuth2 library functions but am running into issues trying to implement based on the Apps Script docs.

Of course, the UrlFetchApp to the Woocommerce endpoint works fine, but when trying to authorize the app at the endpoint, I get the following error:

> Error: An error occurred in the request and at the time were unable to
> send the consumer data.

After subsequent tests with Postman, the callback URL, and return URLs evaluate to the Google Drive splash page and do not execute the function in the script. I am at a loss for how to access the callback function from another source, as it appears that it is only accessible via browser, when logged in.

Below are my functions:

```
let endpoint = {
  protocol: 'https',
  base: '{URL}.com'
}

let params = {}

API.Auth.Authorize = options => {
  endpoint = { ...endpoint, ...{ section: 'wc-auth/v1/authorize' } };
  options = { ...params, ...options };
  let method = 'GET';

  const query =
    method === 'GET' && typeof params === 'object'
      ? Object.keys(options)
          .filter(param => param !== 'payload')
          .map(param => `${param}=${encodeURIComponent(options[param])}`)
          .join('&')
      : options;
  const url = `${endpoint.protocol}://${endpoint.base}/${endpoint.section}${typeof query === 'string' && query.length > 0 ? `?${query}` : ''}`;

  let opts = {
    method: method,
    muteHttpExceptions: true
  };

  return url;
};

const authorize = () => {
  const params = {
    app_name: 'App Name',
    scope: 'read_write',
    user_id: 'abc123',
    return_url: 'https://script.google.com/macros/s/{SCRIPT_ID}/exec',
    callback_url: generateCallbackURL('handleCallback')
  };
  const result = API.Auth.Authorize(params);
  console.log(result);
}

generateCallbackURL = fn => {
  const script_url = `https://script.google.com/macros/d/${ScriptApp.getScriptId()}`;
  const url_suffix = '/usercallback?state=';
  const state_token = ScriptApp.newStateToken().withMethod(fn).withTimeout(120).createToken();
  const callback_url = `${script_url}${url_suffix}${state_token}`;
  return callback_url;
}

const handleCallback = e => {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(JSON.stringify(e));
}
```

I have also tried replacing the `handleCallback` function with a `doPost` function to determine if that would solve the issue. It did not have an effect.

Comment: how is the webapp published?

Comment: The web app is published to execute as `Me` and access is set to `Anyone, even anonymous`

Comment: Is the returnurl and callback url accessible in the incognito tab if your browser?

Comment: The return_url is accessible via an incognito window but the callback_url is not, it redirects to the Google Drive sign in page.

Comment: what happens if you login?

Comment: If I login in the incognito window, it does execute the callback function.

Comment: `/${ScriptApp.getScriptId()}` won't work. id isn't the same as url id

Comment: *If I login in the incognito window, it does execute the callback function*. 1.If that's the case, Woocommerce is probably not sending the state token back or sending it not as a query parameter. 2. If you can't access  without logging in, try the [published url](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/state-token-builder) (same as return url without the exec)

Comment: There appears to be a [bug with the new V8 engine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60236195/847823) where the script does not return the proper published URL.  I have hardcoded the value for the moment, which is the `return_url` sans the `/exec` at the end.  That modified `callback_url` was still prompting me the login.

Comment: Well, if you don't care about security,skip the `/usercallback`, keep the `/exec` itself and parse the values in `doGet()`