# ScriptApp.getService().getUrl() is broken?

Tags: google-apps-script, geturl

why is ScriptApp.getService().getUrl() returning another URL while the web app is on another URL?
after deploying the web app, the link to it is "https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbyLfBVBICZES9w7N5sYzBYHv8oujoNG1FPnmYxGckZHNWSJh-nDWoFaWw5oZs7Cz3M6QA/exec" but on logger.log when i check the getUrl() it is "https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbwFNB8lsKqyaECOo5Nzdj7SmYB26uXarHZD9WSYTLzmxIDLsoEN/exec"

i have a simple function in this web app to test:

```
function myFunction() {
 var url = ScriptApp.getService().getUrl();
 Logger.log(url)
}
```

when i try the link it says "Sorry, unable to open the file at this time.

Please check the address and try again."

what is happening?

*edit: can someone highlight to me what is the purpose of having ScriptApp.getService().getUrl() when it is not doing what it was intended to do?

What i'm trying to do:
I cannot have more than 1 html page in the web app or to be specific, i cannot link to another html page within the web app

Comment: Returns the URL of the web app, if it has been deployed; otherwise returns null. If you are running the development mode web app, this returns the development mode url. So the obvious question is what mode are  you running in?

Comment: okay, as you have said it, it returns the URL of the web app - please tell me this then, why when i execute the returned URL it is not accessible? I've deployed the app at this "https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbyLfBVBICZES9w7N5sYzBYHv8oujoNG1FPnmYxGckZHNWSJh-nDWoFaWw5oZs7Cz3M6QA/exec". In this app i've made a simple function to get value of the URL which is this "https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbwFNB8lsKqyaECOo5Nzdj7SmYB26uXarHZD9WSYTLzmxIDLsoEN/exec". I've made a comparison, they are not the same.

Answer (score 1):

I'm having the same problem.
If I work in development mode, ie with the url ending in /dev, ScriptApp.getService().getUrl() returns the wrong URL.
However, if you deploy and use the published version link ending in /exec, it will work.
I believe this is a bug.
As suggested by this post [ScriptApp.getService().getUrl() points to dev URL. How can I get it to point to exec production URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60232532/scriptapp-getservice-geturl-points-to-dev-url-how-can-i-get-it-to-point-to), I have disabled Chrome V8 from running in general settings and it works.

Comment: okay this is what i get when i published a test web app - "https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbyLfBVBICZES9w7N5sYzBYHv8oujoNG1FPnmYxGckZHNWSJh-nDWoFaWw5oZs7Cz3M6QA/exec" and in this web app i have a simple function to call out the web app url and i get this - "https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbwFNB8lsKqyaECOo5Nzdj7SmYB26uXarHZD9WSYTLzmxIDLsoEN/exec". I've made a comparison, they are not the same even tho it's /exec (means production right?) and best thing is, it's not even executable

Answer (score 0):

I would like to revive this questions as, IMO, ScriptApp.getService().getUrl() is still behaving so that it makes it useless if you are not aware of its flaw and causes a waste of time for developers trying to use it.

To reproduce, do the following.

1. Create a blank spreadsheet and edit the script (Extensions>App Script).
2. Paste the following code :

```
function doGet(e) {
  lParameters = e.parameter;

  if (e.parameter.target == undefined) {
    textOutput = ContentService.createTextOutput("Welcome to the web app.");
    return textOutput;
  }
}

function myFunction() {
  Logger.log(ScriptApp.getScriptId());
  Logger.log(ScriptApp.getService().getUrl());
}
```

3. Execute `myFunction()` from the code editor.  The output should look like :

```
1gG__HE81QjvNBH6OvuyRdZO0qiJkbXM0ljwsJqXv0F6DYB9aVhp82F64
null
```

4. Deploy your script for the first time (Deploy>New Deployment of type WebApp).  I chose 'Anyone within myOrganisation' for 'Who has acess' but I am not sure that it plays a role.  Here is the URL that I can copy from the deployment dialog : `https://script.google.com/a/macros/ballat.be/s/AKfycbx62F71bp90wWlSTFPook8iPfupdaJYuigfk7td0Wes9yo5kAokEBelbFR-L3QOJ2tY/exec`.
5. Run `myFunction()`again from the editor.  Here is the output :

```
1gG__HE81QjvNBH6OvuyRdZO0qiJkbXM0ljwsJqXv0F6DYB9aVhp82F64
https://script.google.com/a/ballat.be/macros/s/AKfycbxgbI9m7FDX8vOFtJ3_NIAETGsfEzkEXZJ83bkYRjI/dev
```

6. Define a time-driven trigger that runs `myFunction()` every minute.  Here is the output :

- for the Head version :

```
1gG__HE81QjvNBH6OvuyRdZO0qiJkbXM0ljwsJqXv0F6DYB9aVhp82F64
https://script.google.com/a/ballat.be/macros/s/AKfycbx13dkx_Jd7f81iDhhToK5QBlz3zjCwcgPJNLINTTT3GrMbayk/exec
```

- for the deployed version (Version 1)

```
1gG__HE81QjvNBH6OvuyRdZO0qiJkbXM0ljwsJqXv0F6DYB9aVhp82F64
https://script.google.com/a/ballat.be/macros/s/AKfycbx62F71bp90wWlSTFPook8iPfupdaJYuigfk7td0Wes9yo5kAokEBelbFR-L3QOJ2tY/exec
```

Let's compare them now (I have removed the first part of the URLs for the sake of readability) :

- Code  editor AKfycbxgbI9m7FDX8vOFtJ3_NIAETGsfEzkEXZJ83bkYRjI/dev
- Trigger head AKfycbx13dkx_Jd7f81iDhhToK5QBlz3zjCwcgPJNLINTTT3GrMbayk/exec
- Trigger v1   AKfycbx62F71bp90wWlSTFPook8iPfupdaJYuigfk7td0Wes9yo5kAokEBelbFR-L3QOJ2tY/exec
- The first URL (when run from the code editor) outputs 'Welcome to the web app." or a more recent text if the code has been updated.
- The second URL does not work at all.
- The last URL ALWAYS outputs 'Welcome to the web app.".

Of course, unaware of this behaviour, I have been trying for several days to get my application working with the second URL...  What a waste of time.  I hope my answer saves time to others and motivates them to move away from Google Workspace-G-Cloud clutter before it becomes worse.