# How to get the test-deployment ID in google app script?

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm trying to get test deployment ID (or URL) in app script. I use this code to get the url :

```
var URL = ScriptApp.getService().getUrl();
```

it returns deployment url but when i run test-deployment, it still returns the deployment url not the test-deployment url. Is there any method i can get the test deployment url/id ?

Comment: This is a known issue,and there is a good workaround here:https://stackoverflow.com/a/64979226/4243927. See if it helps you.

Comment: Did you get further?