# My html form will no longer submit once I added a redirect

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script

I have an html form which was working properly, however it would redirect to
`"{"result":"success","row":1"`.

I have since changed my google app script and added two html pages to my script, a success.html and fail.html which will show a button that redirects to my website. My issue is that now that I've added this, every time I submit I get the failed submition page and nothing is added to my google sheets.

Does my GAS look correct? It is included below.

```
const sheetName = 'Alltechrepair'
const scriptProp = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties()

function initialSetup () {
  const activeSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  scriptProp.setProperty('key', activeSpreadsheet.getId())
}


function doPost(e) {
  const lock = LockService.getScriptLock()
  lock.tryLock(10000)

  try {
    const doc = SpreadsheetApp.openById(scriptProp.getProperty('key'))
    const sheet = doc.getSheetByName(sheetName)

    const headers = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0]
    const nextRow = sheet.getLastRow() + 1

    const newRow = headers.map(function (header) {
      return header === 'Date' ? new Date() : e.parameter[header]
    })

    sheet.getRange(nextRow, 1, 1, newRow.length).setValues([newRow])

    const template = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("redirectSuccess");
    template.url = ScriptApp.getService().getUrl();
    return template.evaluate();
  }

  catch (e) {
    const template = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("redirectError");
    template.url = ScriptApp.getService().getUrl();
    return template.evaluate();
  }

  finally {
    lock.releaseLock()
  }
}
```

I have tried rearranging the code on my GAS, as well as inputing my sheet name.

Comment: Add `catch (e) { console.log(e)` . Also Provide [mcve]

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64979226/7215091

Comment: Question needs opinion, not answer.