# how to get URL of google app script web as of July 2021

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

In my Google Application Script Web application I need to get the URL so I can reload the page. I need to distinguish whether the end user is using  DEV or EXEC environments.

**Server side approach**

With my current settings

- using gmail.com account
- Enable Chrome V8 runtime is checked

is the `ScriptApp.getService().getUrl()` ALWAYS returning EXEC url, never the url of DEV.

I read about Tanaike's [workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60236195/250422) but he said that  `when V8 runtime is disabled, it returns the exec URL`. It works the opposite for me and more importantly I have not idea how to use his suggestion "Method: projects.deployments.list". I am using just script.google.com with my gmail account.

**Browser side approach**

If I want to get the URL on the browser side using `console.log(top.location.pathname)` I get issue with the cross-origin.

```
Uncaught DOMException: Permission denied to access property "pathname" on cross-origin object
```

although I am able to see the URL from browser console

[image]

So my question is whether there is a way or workaround how I can get URL of my GAS web?

Answer (score 1):

This issue has been reported in Google's Issue Tracker here: https://issuetracker.google.com/193820645

Click the "star" next to the issue number to indicate you are affected by ti too.

Comment: thank you for pointing this out. Is there any workaround except disabling the V8 runtime? Or perhaps to get the url on browser side?

Comment: it is my experience that DEV and EXEC url are different. I am not able to create one from the the other one. Did you try your code if you really can access dev created from EXEC url?

Comment: You are correct, they are not the same URLs. I removed that bit from the answer.

Answer (score -1):

## The Workaround Is To Use the Deployment ID

As pointed out, the `exec` and `dev` endpoints seem to be buggy. However, if you look into the actual urls, they all contain deployment IDs. The deployment ID for your `exec` files changes with every version, however your `dev` one never does (as returned by `ScriptApp.getService().getUrl()`). So once you have the `dev` deployment ID down, you can check with the following approach (replace the hard-coded urls with `ScriptApp.getService().getUrl()` of course.

```js
const devDeploymentId = 'AKfycbyF8LrL28jrFWjpTaC8Po7yD-0jV6YpUVG0XJPYCxuCWVRy-9qE';
const re = /(?<=\/)[^\/]+(?=\/(exec|dev)$)/i;

// In Google Apps Script you would have of course const url1 = ScriptApp.getService().getUrl();
const url1 = 'https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbwmBEIYinZ9zCsD_-oFKKn72CQ5IRVR5j3hXRu8xSIE2Vzswje4oRgUskNYzvcGJtGlFg/exec';
const url2 = 'https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbyF8LrL28jrFWjpTaC8Po7yD-0jV6YpUVG0XJPYCxuCWVRy-9qE/exec';

const deployementId1 = url1.match(re)[0];
const deployementId2 = url2.match(re)[0];

console.log(deployementId1, 'is dev:', deployementId1 === devDeploymentId);
console.log(deployementId2, 'is dev:', deployementId2 === devDeploymentId);

console.log(deployementId1.length);
console.log(deployementId2.length);
```

You will also notice that the `dev` deploment ID is shorter (56 characters) than the `exec` one (74 characters), so you may use that as reference. This way when you extract the deployment ids, just check which length it is and you have your answer.