# google.script.run not working from html popup window

Tags: html, google-apps-script

I have tried every variation possible of this and I must be missing something.

It's very simple. I have a yesno window popup that run html code because the UI doesn't really fit my requirements.

Since nothing works as expected, I went back to the very basic and tried this simple code;

https://spreadsheet.dev/custom-dialog-in-google-sheets

```
 function onOpen() {
 SpreadsheetApp
     .getUi()
     .createMenu("Feedback")
     .addItem("Send feedback", "showFeedbackDialog")
     .addToUi();
 }
 function showFeedbackDialog() {
   var widget = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile("test");
   SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(widget, "Send feedback");
 }
```

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
    <input type="button" value="Submit feedback" onclick="alert(Feedback submitted);">
  </body>
 </html>
```

The feedback menu and widget works but the onclick alert doesn't show. In fact the only thing that works is the close action. Running a script doesn't work, running a simple alert doesn't work.

I don't know what I'm missing here.

Help?

Comment: You need quotes around strings you want to alert: `onclick="alert('Feedback submitted');"`

Answer (score -2):

Try putting the google.script.run command right in to the html or into the client side javascript like I have below.  Otherwise everything else your doing is acceptable.

Here's an example of it used in [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53698027/get-the-full-browser-url-in-apps-script/53699995#53699995):

html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <base target="_top">
</head>
  <body>
    <input type="button" value="Submit feedback" onclick="google.script.run.dispAlert('Feedback submitted');">
  </body>
</html>
```

gs:

```
 function dispAlert(s) {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert(s)
 }

 function showFeedbackDialog() {
   var widget = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile("ah2");
   SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(widget, "Send feedback");
 }
```

demo:

[image]